# Return all results from xpath Dom parse?

Tags: php, dom, xpath, domdocument

I want to scrape a website using PHP, 
Here is the code :

```
<?php  
$url = 'http://sample.com';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$contents = $xpath->query('//p[@class="ac"]');
$content = $dom->saveHTML($contents->item(0));
echo $content;
echo '<br />';
 ?>
```

But it will return only first p tag which has "ac" class, But I want it to return all results . So I edited the code to :

```
<?php  
$url = 'http://sample.com';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$contents = $xpath->query('//p[@class="ac"]');
$content = $dom->saveHTML($contents->item(0));
for($i=0;$i<$contents->length; $i++){
    echo $contents->item($i);
}
echo '<br />';
 ?>
```

But , It gives me this error :

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string in

What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$contents->item($i) is DomElement object. You can print  `$contents->item($i)->nodeValue` to get, for example , text of paragraph or in such way `$content =  $dom->saveHTML($contents->item($i))` to get outerhtml.

But I would prefer such loop

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
foreach($xpath->query('//p[@class="ac"]') as $content) 
   echo  $dom->saveHTML($content);
echo '<br />';
```

Comment: Thanks ! Works Great !

Comment: how can I replace a text in html output here? should I use this way ? echo $dom->saveHTML(str_replace('text1', 'text2', $content));

Comment: `echo str_replace('text1', 'text2', $dom->saveHTML($content));`

Comment: You're Great splash !